# PHP difference between the imagefilter's parameter values IMG_FILTER_SELECTIVE_BLUR and the IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR

Tags: php, gd, imagefilter

What is the difference between the imagefilter's parameters IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR and IMG_FILTER_SELECTIVE_BLUR?

Comment: I think it's the algorithm used.

Comment: @RAS, while adding [tag:imagefilter], be sure to add [tag:gd] as well.  imagefilter is a GD function.

Comment: @Charles, I thought adding imagefilter will suffice but ok, I'll take care.

Answer (score 2):

both are different image filter algorithm

> ```
> IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR: Blurs the image using the Gaussian method.
>
> IMG_FILTER_SELECTIVE_BLUR: Blurs the image.
>
> http://www.phpf1.com/manual/imagefilter.html
> ```